# Docker-compose fails with error "No command specified"

Tags: node.js, docker

Starting the container with the run command

```
docker run -it -d -p 8888:8888 install_advisor node src/server
```

works as expected. But trying to bring it up using docker-compose results in the error:

> "ERROR: for advisor  Cannot create container for service advisor: No
>   command specified"

What am I doing wrong?

Contents of docker-compose.yml

```
advisor:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: DockerfileAdvisor
  ports:
    - "8888:8888"
  restart: always
  privileged: true
```

Contents of DockerfileAdvisor

```
FROM XYZ
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "src/server" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised that your solution doesn't work as it is. But you can probably fix it in several ways. Here some suggestions:

1) Change your `DockerFileAdvisor` file to

```
FROM XYZ
COMMAND [ "node", "src/server" ]
```

2) If `DockerFileAdvisor` really contains just the two rows that are shown in your question, you don't even need it. Just specify `image: XYZ` and `command: [ "node", "src/server" ]` in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
advisor:
    image: XYZ
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    command: [ "node", "src/server" ]
```

Maybe you'd like to take a look on Docker documentation how `ENTRYPOINT` and `COMMAND` directives play together. In short, with `ENTRYPOINT` you can make an image to look like an executable and use `COMMAND` to just pass parameters for it.

Comment: Great, nice to hear it! :)